# SharpZipLib extracted file size

Tags: c#, sharpziplib

Is there a way to find out what the total size of the unextracted archive would be when extracted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
ZipFile zFile = new ZipFile(myZipFileName);
long uSize = 0;
foreach (ZipEntry e in zFile) {
    if ( e.IsFile ) {
        uSize += e.Size;
    }
}
```